# among the rows meeting one criteria, count how many of the 5 largest also meet another criteria

Tags: excel-2016

In a large table, I want to look at only the rows from a given sample(say sample1), and among them find the 5 with the largest probability(another parameter in the table), and then count how many of them that meet a third criteria, with is Cell type=1. I want to be able to do that for all the samples in the large table.

Have tried to use LARGE((range=criteria)*(range);{1;2;3;4;5}) together with a COUNTIFS, but can't seem to build two criteria and two ranges into it. With the COUNTIFS, it will just take the 5 rows with the largest probability in the whole table, and see how many of them are also sample1 and cell type=1. 
I guess the solution is some kind of nested IF or COUNTIF(don't know about that is even possible), but just can't get it to work.

Have tried to use this one:
=COUNTIFS(Table1[Sample];"sample1";Table1[Cell type];"1";Table1[Probability];LARGE((Table1[Sample]="sample1")*(Table1[Probability]);{1;2;3;4;5}))
Which returns 1

Have also tried this one:
=COUNTIF(Table1[Sample];LARGE(IF(AND(Table1[Cell type]=1;Table1[Sample]="sample1");Table1[Probability]);{1;2;3;4;5}))

Which returns 0

I have run out of good ideas and really need some help, thanks!

To make it even more clear, with the data below, among the rows from sample1 only, I want to count how many of the 5 rows with the highest probability(within sample1) that are also cell type = 1? The results should be:

sample1 = 3

sample2 = 4

sample3 = 5

---

Sample      --  Cell type   --      Probability

sample1     --  1       --      0,95

sample1     --  1       --0,9

sample1     --  1       --  0,85

sample1     --  0       --  0,8

sample1     --  0       --  0,75

sample1     --  0       --  0,7

sample1     --  0       --  0,65

sample2     --  1       --  0,97

sample2     --  1       --  0,95

sample2     --  1       --0,93

sample2     --  1       --0,91

sample2     --  0       --0,89

sample2     --  0       --0,87

sample2     --  0       --0,85

sample2     --  0       --0,83

sample2     --  1       --0,81

sample3     --1     --0,87

sample3     --1     --0,86

sample3     --1     --0,85

sample3     --1     --0,84

sample3     --1     --0,83

sample3     --1     --0,82

sample3     --1     --0,81

sample3     --1     --0,8

Comment: Hi guys. If my question is unclear, ambiguous or missing some essential detail, please let me know. I'm new to asking question on StackOverflow, so if I'm violating some convention, just tell me:-) 
And if you think it can't be done, I will just try to find another way, maybe saving the data as csv and taking it over in python:-).

Comment: I have tried this one: =COUNT(IF(Table1[Sample]=H8;IF(Table1[[ Cell type ]]=1;LARGE((Table1[Sample]=H8)*(Table1[[ Cell type ]]=1)*Table1[[ Probability]];{1;2;3;4;5}))))   Where H8 contains the string "sample1".   This one gives 3, which is correct, but for some reason it doesnt work for sample2 and sample3 for some reason...